# how do you preserve array indices in python implementation of Fractional Knapsack?

Tags: python, knapsack-problem

I'm working on the Fractional Knapsack problem. Essentially I'm given lists containing weights of items and prices as well as a number for total capacity.  The goal is to find the greatest value possible out of fractional combinations of items up to the capacity of the knapsack. The order of the two lists is important because the first weight corresponds to the first price and so on.  I'm implementing the solution in Python, and I know a key step is to calculate value per unit weight for all items and then sort it in descending order, which I did using `unit_prices = [a/b for a, b in zip(prices, weights)]`

and then `unit_prices.sort(reverse=True)` My question is how do we link the sorted unit_prices to the original indices for prices and weights?  I can't sort them all individually because the indices wouldn't necessarily line up the way they did originally.  I need to preserve the index for a given price per unit weight so I can figure out how much of that item to get and what its value is.

My instinct here is to sort all of them together, or rather to use the sorting order of unit_prices to determine the order of the other lists, but I am unsure on how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having two separate lists, represent each item as a single object.  For example:

```
from typing import NamedTuple


class Item(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    price: float
    weight: float


items = [
    Item("cheese", 1.0, 1.0), 
    Item("bread", 0.25, 0.5), 
    Item("milk", 2.0, 1.5)
]
```

Now you have a list of `items` that each has a `name`, `price`, and `weight`, so you can very easily do stuff like:

```
items.sort(key=lambda item: item.price/item.weight, reverse=True)
```

Since each item is a single (and immutable) unit, sorting the list of items doesn't cause you to lose track of which price goes with which weight or which name.